# how set value of current operating system to default operating system -by c# code or by script

Tags: c#, bcdedit

how set value of current operating system to default operating system -by c# code or by script.
manually : control panel -> System -> change system -> advanced ->setting -> (startup and recovery) 
checked the default operating system.
I do it by this script, I want to set in  the current operating id:
bcdedit /default

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you clarify exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

The answer you are looking for is:

> **bcdedit  /default  {current}**

You should execute this command line from a c# program which has aquired administrative rights
or else it will fail.

Windows BCD store is accessible only with admin rights.

Alternatively you can use WMI to access BCD store programmatically.
The equivalent program code for the command line above is 10-20 lines of c# code.

You set the "DefaultObject" element of {bootmgr} object to {current}.

Comment: It worked for me. Just make sure that you'll run CMD as admin.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start("bcdedit.exe", "/default " + yourOSId);
```

Comment: how can I get the current operating id? (yourOSId)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've tried `Process.Start("bcdedit.exe", "/v" );` but got error message `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'` (here is the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/kvJFDKt.png)). When I am doing same things manually via cmd, it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot change/set the OS version. You can only [read](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/501/Default.aspx) it.

Comment: you can select the default and restart using bcdedit command line tool